Extract arguments type from function intersection based on first argument value
Given https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oAo0QG7AFxQHIBjAewDsAzASwCcBbCAEwIBooBDGgc3gH0AGfAG8oJLBBoB3GlWAR8AIxIkANhHZkoAXwCUKAHxQsJKoz0AydJhz5iGohDXM9yQ8dM6A3AChvoSFAAogAewDTsRMAAgtwAPDBsgYaoMFAQoRBkjPDo2HhBbJw8+FSUElAACi5uJoxQAPyVUPhk2BI+-tAhYRHAAMLk1PRMMTzxybBpGVk51vnEg7QMzIXcJWU0UACq1Ua1DdvNUK3iND5+4F3iZMAVnOwMcjTw8YkTqelyM7k2UKUU5RggTYADowUV4OsAZtRvBdu46o00ECpl9skEDrCjicJHoWm0zr4APRE44kJCSEg0ADWpS4FwCA0oSyYd3CjwkOVQgWut3uHOe8QQwDYC2Zw2Y+gA2vwALrnEnsFTwEhkilU2lkemdJrc0LhSKjIWIUWkcXLAj6c46qJkckACwkMBoIBQQX1vSZQ2WsONwCtQA
I'm basically trying to extract/infer type of argument when one of intersecting functions have first argument value of "something".
Consider this Vue example:
type Test = ((evt: 'confirmed', args_0: { overwrite: boolean }) => void) & ((evt: 'canceled') => void);

type ExtractArg<T, E> = T extends (evt: E, args: infer P) => void ? P : never;
type ExtractConfirmedArgs<T> = T extends (evt: 'confirmed', arg: infer U) => void ? U : never;

type EventParameters<T, E> = T extends (evt: infer TE, ...args: infer Args) => void ? (TE extends E ? Args : never) : never;

// not working
type ConfirmedParameters = EventParameters<Test, 'confirmed'>[0];

//also not working
type P = ExtractArg<Test, 'confirmed'>;

type AnotherTry = ExtractConfirmedArgs<Test>;

I'd want to extract the type so type ConfirmedArgs = { overwrite: boolean } from type Test, but I couldn't find if it is possible and AI was also not really helpful, though I would think that code above should work.
Is there something I'm doing wrong here or is it impossible to extract such thing from intersection and only possible to do it with unions ?
Typescript version is 5.4.5.
The closest answer I could find is Typesciprt Dynamic function arguments with GENERICS, but I'm not convinced if it's the same case here.
Cheers

This is not possible. You should instead define Test to be an intersection of the individual function types. There is no reason to have to "reverse engineer" the parameter types later.

Function intersection is equivalent to overloading, and overload types don't give you a way to enumerate the call signatures without various hacks; see linked q/a for more info; using that approach here gives this code which may or may not meet your needs.
